# jquery selector for <select> having exactly 2 children

Tags: jquery

I want a jquery selector which selects all `<select>` having exactly 2 options in it.

I tried everything but unable to find any suitable answer.

Comment: Can you post your tried code ?

Comment: And the DOM structure you want to target? (Pictures -- in this case, as markup -- are worth 1024 words.)

Comment: use the [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function: `$('select').filter(function() { return $(this).children().length == 2; })`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS doesn't have a selector construct for counting the *number* of children, so you won't get just a single selector for this. Instead, you can use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var selectsWithTwoOptions = $("select").filter(function() {
    return this.options.length == 2;
});
```

Or in ES2015:

```
let selectsWithTwoOptions = $("select").filter(() => this.options.length == 2);
```

Example:

```js
var selectsWithTwoOptions = $("select").filter(function() {
    return this.options.length == 2;
});
selectsWithTwoOptions.css({
  color: "green",
  fontWeight: "bold"
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 12em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select>
    <option>I have one option</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select>
    <option>I have two options</option>
    <option>two</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select>
    <option>I have three options</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select>
    <option>I have four options</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
    <option>four</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```